# Install of gems is not verbose, despite .gemrc

Tags: ruby, rubygems, verbosity

This is my `.gemrc`

```
:verbose: true
```

I have copied the same `.gemrc` into `/root/` and into `/home/vagrant/`, to make sure that using `sudo` isn't messing with me.

I have checked the setting is working with:

```
root@vagrant $ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 484) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

The problem is that that when I execute:

```
root@vagrant $ gem install knife-solo
```

I get a "less verbose" output than when I execute:

```
root@vagrant $ gem install knife-solo --verbose
```

even though the `.gemrc` file sets the `verbose` as `true`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is that the right format for the `.gemrc`? I'm not sure about the leading `:`.

Comment: It should not matter, since `gem env` confirms that verbose is set correctly, no? In any case, I tried it without the leading `:` and the result was exactly the same.

Comment: Yeah, you're right there, I just noticed that. That is a fairly old version of Rubygems though. Does this persist in the newer 2.2 series?

Comment: I do not know. Do you recommend me change to version 2.2?

Comment: For testing at least. 1.8.3 dates from 2011 and might be using an older-style `.gemrc`. It is possible to adjust the version with `gem update --system x.x.x` where that's a version number you want, so you can always roll back.

Answer (score 2):

To set the `--verbose` or `--no-verbose` option for the gem command, add the command to the gem key in `~/.gemrc`:

```
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc --verbose
```